# Conditional lsof loop in bash script

Tags: macos, bash

I found this example of a conditional lsof loop and want to adapt it to my situation.

```
typeset fSrc="/path/to/sourcedir"
typeset fTgt="/path/to/targetdir"

while : ; do
   ls /path/to/sourcedir | while read file ; do
      if [ $(lsof $fSrc/$file | wc -l) -gt 1 ] ; then
           echo "file $file still loading, skipping it"
      else
           mv $fSrc/$file $fTgt/$file
           echo "file $file completed upload, moving it"
      fi
   done
done
```

My example would be more like this:

```
while any files are present in "/pathto/sourcedir"; do
    if [ lsof "any file" in "/pathto/sourcedir" is being written or modified ]; then
       echo "Files being written or modified, exiting"
       exit
    else
       do something
    fi
done
```

Can this be done?  Is my logic somewhat close to correct?

Comment: yep, I'd say (without any testing), that you're very close. Do you know about the shell debug/trace feature, add `set -vx` and `set +vx` pairs to turn on/off debugging/trace. While debugging is on, with `set -vx`, you'll see each line or block of code before it executes, and then each line as it executes, preceded with `+ ` and the command with each variable replaced with its values. You may also occasionally need things like `printf "#DBG:var=$var\n"` to see what is happening. Good luck.